# Как автоматически влючить геоданные

Tags: java, android, геолокация, gps

Всем привет. Мне нужно реализовать метод, который будет автоматически включать геоданные(GPS) после разрешения пользователя. Пример такой реализации на скриншоте. Я пока никак не могу её реализовать. На гитхабе ничего дельного не нашел. Возможно, у кого-нибудь есть ссылки, исходники или образцы кода? Я буду очень благодарен.

*Примечание: извините за возможные ошибки, русский язык не мой родной, надеюсь, вы меня поймёте. Спасибо!*

[image: Вот такую функцию хочу реализовать]

Comment: Скорее всего минус вам поставили за множество ошибок в тексте, демонстрирующих ваше неуважение к читающим, а также из-за малой понятности сути вопроса - что именно вам нужно и что именно не получилось - непонятно.

Comment: Спасибо Ирюй,хотел в цикле он старт проврить есть ли подключение геоданных и если нет выдать такой диалог для влючения  .Уже сделал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попросить пользователя включить GPS можно. Если он нажмёт ОК, то датчик включится автоматически. Вот код:

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiGPSClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                        .build();

            LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000 * 60 * 60); //1 hour
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                    .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);

            PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                    LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiGPSClient,
                            builder.build());

            result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
                    Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
                    switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS: {
                            //do something
                            break;
                        }
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED: {
                            //do something
                            break;
                        }
                        default: break;
                }
            }});
```

Ваш код пишите там, где я поставил комментарии  *//do something*

Надеюсь, это поможет вам. Удачи!

Comment: Да спасибо !Очень помогло это то что я искал)добавил его в метод onStart и сделал пару изменений)все как на масле получилось!)спасибо большое