# Runtime permissions в Delphi 10.1 Berlin для Android 6 (23 sdk)

Tags: android, delphi, permissions, runtime, delphi-10-berlin

Добрый день всем! 
У меня следующая задача. Мне необходимо понять как запрашивать разрешения на использование gps и другие ему подобные "опасные" разрешения на Android 6 (sdk 23) во время выполнения программы на устройстве! Моя программа написана на Rad Studio 10.1 Berlin (firemonkey) и все разрешения прописаны в манифесте, однако манифест в Android 6 уже ничего не решает! Где можно найти информацию по этому вопросу?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
<manifest
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.embarcadero.TransPorter"
          android:versionCode="53"
          android:versionName="1.5.2"
          android:installLocation="preferExternal">

  <!-- This is the platform API where NativeActivity was introduced. -->
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="True" />
  <application
               android:persistent="False"
               android:restoreAnyVersion="False"
               android:label="TransPorter"
               android:debuggable="False"
               android:largeHeap="False"
               android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
               android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
               android:hardwareAccelerated="true">


    <!-- Our activity is a subclass of the built-in NativeActivity framework class.
             This will take care of integrating with our NDK code. -->
    <activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity" 
              android:label="TransPorter" 
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden" 
              android:launchMode="singleTask">
      <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
      <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="TransPorter" />
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver 
       android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.notifications.FMXNotificationAlarm" />

  </application>
</manifest>
<!-- END_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
```

Comment: Вот я недавно это спрашивал
[включение геоданных](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/602262/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)

Comment: Это написано на чистом андройде (Java)! Как это сделать на андройде - мне понятно. А вот как в firemonkey (Object Pascal)?

Comment: Печаль!..... Понял, что можно только скачать программу и вручную в разделе разрешений выставить переключатели вправо, чтобы открыть доступ к нужной службе или сенсору устройства!